# Worst-case running time to print binary search tree

Tags: arrays, data-structures, time-complexity, binary-tree

What is the worst-case running time to print out all the values sorted in a binary search tree containing N positive integers in ascending order?

I guessed it’s O(n) since n is number of elements that will be printed out

Comment: Depends on how you do it. But yes, if you do the default infix tree traversal it will be O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Algorithms have best case and worst case running times not problems.

"Print out all the items in a balanced binary search tree in order" is a problem statement.

*Tree traversal*, however,  is an algorithm. It comes in three flavors: inorder, preorder, or postorder. If you do the traversal inorder -- meaning traverse the left branch, then visit the root, then traverse the right branch -- and print out the items when visiting them, you will print them out in the proper order. Each item will be visited once and only once, so the best, worst, and average running times are all O(n).